# Как передать данные из бд Oracle в бд на хостинге?

Tags: php, mysql, oracle

БД на хостинге MySQL. Есть представление в Oracle, как передать на хостинг?
Может через php вытаскивать данные и пересылать на хостинг? Если так можно,то есть у кого пример?

Comment: **CREATE DATABASE LINK** https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm

Comment: @Akina это сработает даже если бд физически на разных серверах?

Comment: А какая разница, один сервер или два разных? был бы доступ...

Comment: @Akina в линке на увидел, как он поймет с каким именно серверов соединяться? Имею ввиду,например,url и тд

Comment: Читайте про Oracle Heterogeneous Services. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14232/admin.htm Для доступа к не-Оракловым БД используется именно он.

Comment: Если нужна постоянная синхронизация данных между Oracle и MySQL возможно стоит использовать Oracle golden gate